# Editar nombre de las imagenes de una carpeta en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas compañeros colegas necesito su ayuda, estoy intentando renombrar las imagenes de una carpeta pero al momento de hacerlo me aparece el error " El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso " en base sus experiencias a que se refiere y como se puede solucionar? saludos de antemano colegas

```
public void ActualizarImagenes(HttpPostedFileBase carpetarchivo)
{
                string carpetaImagenes = @"D:\Users\Desktop\PRUEBA";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(carpetaImagenes);
    
    
                string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(carpetaImagenes);
    
    
                Pesaje pesaje = new Pesaje();
    
    
    
    
                DirectoryInfo directorio = new DirectoryInfo(carpetaImagenes);
                FileInfo[] archivos8 = directorio.GetFiles();
    
               
    
                foreach (string archivo in archivos)
                {
                    string rutaOrigen = archivo;
                    string rutaDestino = Server.MapPath("/areas/images/recibos/jjj.JPG");
    
                    
    
    
                    try
                    {
                        // Código de renombrado de archivos
                        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(rutaOrigen);
                        fileInfo.MoveTo(rutaDestino);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Manejo de la excepción
                        Console.WriteLine("Error al renombrar el archivo: " + ex.Message);
                    }
    
                }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: No me queda claro, quieres renombrarlo o moverlo de carpeta?

Comment: Si estas depurando desde VS/VSC este debe haber sido abierto en modo "Administrador" si estas ejecutando la aplicacion ya compilada, debes haber ejecutado la app en modo Administrador, no puedes alterar archivos en cualquier carpeta en la que no tengas permisos.
Prueba creando una carpeta con permisos publicos y veras que ahi si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el método [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) para construir la nueva ruta, y [File.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-7.0) para reemplazar el archivo modificado.

En el siguiente ejemplo tengo la imagen png "Captua1.png" en el disco D y la quiero renombrar agregando a "Captura-2023.jpg".

```
string rutaArchivo = "D:\\Captura1.png"; 
string nuevoNombre = "Captura1-2023.jpg"; 
string rutaNueva = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaArchivo), nuevoNombre);
System.IO.File.Move(rutaArchivo, rutaNueva);
```